# Apache Camel stops poll after exception instead of resuming with next exchange

Tags: java, jpa, apache-camel

So I have a Camel route copying data from one database to multiple others:

```
var route = from("jpa://Data").choice();
        
for (var dbConnection : dbConnections) {
    String name = dbConnection.getName();
    route = route.when(simple("${body.name} == '" + name + "' ")).to("jpa://Data" + name).endChoice();
}
route.otherwise().process(ex -> {
    logger.info("Data.name={} not found in dbConnections", name);
}).endChoice().end();
```

So the `Data.name` field determines the target JPA endpoint.

Now let's say I have databases `A` and `B`, but I made a typo and therefore `A` is inaccessible. This will cause a `SQLException` as soon as a `Data` entity with `name==A` gets routed. Afterwards, the poll stops and (after the configured `delay`) another poll starts, but will immediatly crash at the same point.

All the while, my `Data` entities with `name==B` are stuck, even though the db connection for `B` exists and is valid. I took a look at the `onException` clause, but I wasn't able to configure the route to resume with the next exchange after those exceptions. Any tips?

Comment: Within the `onException(SQLException.class)` block you should define something along the line of `.handled(true)` as explained [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/exception-clause.html#_marking_exceptions_as_handled). You can also try using `doTry()` and `doCatch(...)` or split the returned data into own exchanges, forward these to seda routes and in case of a failure simply stop the exchange from being routed further. There are lots of ways how you could handle this case

Comment: ```onException(SQLException.class).handled(true);``` worked flawlessly, not sure why I dismissed it earlier! Thanks